# Custom Menu hiding my website content

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

i followed this website to built a custom navigation menu:

http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/115/how-to-create-mobile-friendly-html-5-css-3-fixed-responsive-navigation-menu/

but the content does not show on my website as it gets overwritten by the navigation bar. Any idea how to fix this?

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nav_bar.css">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {
                        $("#navToggle a").click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $("header > nav").slideToggle();
                            $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
                        });

                        $(window).resize(function() {
                            if ($(window).width() >= "600") {
                                $("header > nav").css("display", "block");

                                if ($("#logo").attr('class') == "menuDown") {
                                    $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
                                }
                            } else {
                                $("header > nav").css("display", "none");
                            }
                        });

                        $("header > nav > ul > li > a")
                                .click(
                                        function(e) {
                                            if ($(window).width() <= "600") {
                                                if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
                                                    e.preventDefault();
                                                    $(this)
                                                            .siblings()
                                                            .slideToggle("fast")
                                                    $(this)
                                                            .children(".toggle")
                                                            .html(
                                                                    $(this)
                                                                            .children(
                                                                                    ".toggle")
                                                                            .html() == 'close' ? 'expand'
                                                                            : 'close');
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo" class="menuUp">
            <h1>Username</h1>
            <div id="navToggle">
                <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
                <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
    <p>testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData</p>



</body>
</html>
```

My Css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

header>div#logo {
    line-height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

header>.menuDown {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

header>.menuUp {
    box-shadow: none;
}

header>div#logo>h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle:hover>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

header>nav {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    flex: 1;
    transform: 300ms all ease;
}

header nav>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

header nav>ul>li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: relative;
}

header nav>ul>li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
}

header nav>ul>li>a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 250ms all ease;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>a {
    color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 100;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li:hover>a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    header>div#logo>div#navToggle {
        display: none;
    }
    header {
        background-color: white;
        flex-direction: row;
        line-height: 90px;
        padding: 0 3rem;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    header>div#logo {
        background-color: transparent;
        line-height: 90px;
    }
    header>div#logo>h1 {
        color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
    }
    header>nav {
        background-color: transparent;
        display: block;
    }
    header>nav>ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    header nav>ul>li {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    header nav>ul>li>a {
        padding: 0 1.25rem;
    }
    header>nav>ul>li:hover>nav {
        background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
        border-radius: .25em;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        display: block;
        line-height: 3em;
        right: -50%;
        width: 196px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works fine. Your content isn't overwritten by the navigation bar. It's just behind it. 
Check positioning of the elements. Your header is positioned as fixed. You can just turn off this property and you will see your text.

If you want to keep it fixed, just extend your 'resize' function. Just count the height of a header element and just move the next element on the counted value (`top` or `padding` properties, or maybe `transform: translateY(y)` if you are brave enough).

chiliNUT's answer with *150px* isn't useful. Since you have 90px line-height. And even if you use *90px* instead of *150px*, it will fail when window's size is between *600px* and *764px*, since your menu will become bigger: *2* lines with *90px* line-height, thus you will have *180px* height. Your nav bar's height depends on its content (number of lines) and line-height. 
The idea of element addition is pretty good. But you still need to resize the event to make it work. And still one more element is in your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The header has `position:fixed` so it will "stick" to the top of the page. Since that is the case, you need to push all of your content down below the header, since right now it is behind it. One way to do that is to insert a shim div between the header and your content, something like

```
</header>
<div style='display:block;height:150px;></div>
<h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
//...
```

See snippet below:

```js
 $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {
                        $("#navToggle a").click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $("header > nav").slideToggle();
                            $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
                        });

                        $(window).resize(function() {
                            if ($(window).width() >= "600") {
                                $("header > nav").css("display", "block");

                                if ($("#logo").attr('class') == "menuDown") {
                                    $("#logo").toggleClass("menuUp menuDown");
                                }
                            } else {
                                $("header > nav").css("display", "none");
                            }
                        });

                        $("header > nav > ul > li > a")
                                .click(
                                        function(e) {
                                            if ($(window).width() <= "600") {
                                                if ($(this).siblings().size() > 0) {
                                                    e.preventDefault();
                                                    $(this)
                                                            .siblings()
                                                            .slideToggle("fast")
                                                    $(this)
                                                            .children(".toggle")
                                                            .html(
                                                                    $(this)
                                                                            .children(
                                                                                    ".toggle")
                                                                            .html() == 'close' ? 'expand'
                                                                            : 'close');
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                    });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

header>div#logo {
    line-height: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

header>.menuDown {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

header>.menuUp {
    box-shadow: none;
}

header>div#logo>h1 {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 2.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>div#logo>div#navToggle:hover>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

header>nav {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    flex: 1;
    transform: 300ms all ease;
}

header nav>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

header nav>ul>li {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: relative;
}

header nav>ul>li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
}

header nav>ul>li>a {
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 250ms all ease;
}

header>nav>ul>li:hover>a {
    color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 100;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
    transition: 300ms all ease;
}

header>nav>ul>li>nav>ul>li:hover>a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    header>div#logo>div#navToggle {
        display: none;
    }
    header {
        background-color: white;
        flex-direction: row;
        line-height: 90px;
        padding: 0 3rem;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    header>div#logo {
        background-color: transparent;
        line-height: 90px;
    }
    header>div#logo>h1 {
        color: rgb(140, 193, 193);
    }
    header>nav {
        background-color: transparent;
        display: block;
    }
    header>nav>ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    header nav>ul>li {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    header nav>ul>li>a {
        padding: 0 1.25rem;
    }
    header>nav>ul>li:hover>nav {
        background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
        border-radius: .25em;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        display: block;
        line-height: 3em;
        right: -50%;
        width: 196px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div id="logo" class="menuUp">
            <h1>Username</h1>
            <div id="navToggle">
                <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
                <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<div style='display:block;height:100px;'></div>
    <h1>Welcome to my Website!</h1>
    <p>testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData
    testData testDatatestData testDatatestData testData</p>
```